# What is scheduling policy -1?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, scheduler

I am writing a utility to dynamically change tasks' scheduling policies on Android.  I am primarily using the sched_getscheduler() and sched_setscheduler() syscalls to accomplish this.

In sched.h (in the kernel), the scheduling policies are defined as:

```
/*
 * Scheduling policies
 */ 
#define SCHED_NORMAL    0
#define SCHED_FIFO      1
#define SCHED_RR        2
#define SCHED_BATCH     3
/* SCHED_ISO: reserved but not implemented yet */
#define SCHED_IDLE      5
```

However, there are some tasks (primarily IRQs, although not every IRQ) which return a -1 when sched_getscheduler() is called.

I found the definition of the sched_getscheduler() syscall in the kernel in sched.c:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(sched_getscheduler, pid_t, pid)
{
struct task_struct *p;
int retval;

if (pid < 0)
    return -EINVAL;

retval = -ESRCH;
rcu_read_lock();
p = find_process_by_pid(pid);
if (p) {
    retval = security_task_getscheduler(p);
    if (!retval)
        retval = p->policy
            | (p->sched_reset_on_fork ? SCHED_RESET_ON_FORK : 0);
}
rcu_read_unlock();
return retval;
}
```

ESRCH and EINVAL are defined as 3 and 22, respectively.  This is leaving me at a loss for how sched_getscheduler() is returning -1.

Some background information for those who are interested.  I am using Linux Kernel 3.1.10 on Android 4.4.2 on the first generation Nexus 7.  The IRQs that are returning -1 specifically are: 210-host_sp, 214-host_sp, and 218-host_sp.  I know these IRQs to be related to the graphics driver, however there may also be others that I have not noticed.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most other userspace functions, `sched_getscheduler` returns -1 to indicate an error.

To get the actual error code, see `errno`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback.  Actually I am aware of errno.  I apologize, I probably should have phrased my question more along the lines of "**Why** would certain processes return -1?" I am digging into the kernel code at the moment.  I don't believe it should have anything to do with the priority or the UID of the process, as I am able to successfully call sched_getscheduler on other processes of the same UID, furthermore I am able to call sched_getscheduler on processes running at the highest RT priority.

Comment: The kernel told you why it did not return a scheduling policy. So far, you have kept the value of `errno` a secret.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not use errno in my original program.  I have since recompiled it using errno and now I am unable to repeat the issue I was having previously.  I appreciate your feedback, and I will start using errno from the beginning in the future.